# Gigabit network connection in Ubuntu issue with new hardware

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkcard, realtek

Probably its typical issue, but I couldn’t found the answer. Sometime ago I had mini-ITX server worked on [ZOTAC IONITX-G-E](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813500037). It was managed by Ubuntu 10.10. I setuped Gigabit network with this server. I installed one additional network card ([Planet ENW-9700](http://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/product_ov.php?id=5141). It's PCI-E x1 card) because it did some routing, that's why I need two network cards. I used [DGS-1005D](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/dgs-1005d-5-port-10-100-1000-gigabit-desktop-switch) as Gigabit switch. It worked fine, Planet network card had Gigabit network connection. When I used it, network speed was ~40-50Mb\s.

After that a month ago I decided to do upgrade, because that system wasn't enough for me. I bought new [Asus P8H77-I](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H77I/) motherboard with Intel i3-3225. I installed it in the same box instead of Zotac motherboard and installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.10. But somehow network card doesn't work as Gigabit connection. Distance between server and switch is 6-7 meters.

I googled for it, and found some similar topics for Realtek NIC(this motherboard uses Realtek 8111F). So, based on some manuals I download latest Realtek drivers from [this page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), compiled them and installed. I disabled previous one RTL8169 driver that used before. But after that there is no Gigabit connection. I tried to force it by

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
```

but it didn't do anything. Connection speed remained 100Mb\s.
Here is ethtool eth0 output

```
 Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                           drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Could you please suggest anything?

I have the last option to install Planet NIC PCI-E x1 into PCI-E x16 slot and use it as before, but I don't want to occupy the only one PCI-E slot

Comment: Just some basics:
Same cable used as before? (And it does have all 8 wires wired up?)
I've had some lightning-caused problems with a D-Link Gigabit switch where ports would only operate at 10Mbps...
You might also want to try a live CD (say a Windows 7 install CD to see if it depends on the booted OS, which might help narrow down the problem between hardware and drivers...)

Comment: Yes, I used the same cable. I didn't do anything with it and with switch. They are remain the same. I'll try LiveCD, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried LiveCD and it was the same - 100Mb. I tried to install side by side Windows 7, and after that installed drivers for network card from ASUS site. Network started to work, but network speed was 100Mb.

Then I installed my old Planet NIC and it started work as 1000Mb, and real transfer speed is 50-70Mb/s. So, I'm not sure about reason of it.. Maybe issue is in network cable and builtin NIC couldn't work on high speed. And somehow external card works fine.